# Unable to Write Inline function in Matlab

Tags: windows, matlab, compilation, system, aggregate

Unable to Write Inline Aggregate function in Matlab.
X1, X2 are array variables. And mb and nb are size of BUS DATA.
V is the voltage function, delta is the angle.

```
% objf=inline('sum(V(mb)^2+V(nb)^2-2*V(mb)*V(nb)*cos(delta(mb)-delta(nb)))','mb','nb');
% old code running 
objf=inline('4*x1^2-2.1*x1^4+(x1^6)/3+x1*x2-4*x2^2+4*x2^4','x1','x2');**
```

***Error using inlineeval (line 15)
Error in inline expression ==> sum(V(mb).^2+V(nb).^2-2.*V(mb).*V(nb).*cos(delta(mb)-delta(nb)))
 Undefined function 'V' for input arguments of type 'double'.
Error in inline/subsref (line 24)
    INLINE_OUT_ = inlineeval(INLINE_INPUTS_, INLINE_OBJ_.inputExpr, INLINE_OBJ_.expr);
Error in deeee (line 48)
fx=objf(x(:,1),x(:,2));***

**where variable aer defined as below..**

```
busdata = bus; % ARRAY OF INPUTs
j=sqrt(-1);
P=[];Q=[];
nb=busdata(:,1);
kb=busdata(:,2);Vm=busdata(:,3);deltad=busdata(:, 4);Pd=0.8*busdata(:,5)/basemva;Qd=.8*busdata(:,6)/basemva;
Pg=busdata(:,7)/basemva;Qg=busdata(:,8)/basemva;Bsh=busdata(:,11);Qmin=busdata(:,9)/basemva;Qmax=busdata(:,10)/basemva;
G=real(Ybus);B=imag(Ybus);slb=find(kb==1);pv=find(kb==2);pq=find(kb==0);pvq=find(kb~=1);npv=length(pv);
npq=length(pq);npvq=length(pvq);nbus=max(nb);
delta(nb) = pi/180*deltad(nb);
V(nb) = Vm(nb).*(cos(delta(nb))+j*sin(delta(nb)))';
P(nb)=(Pg(nb)-Pd(nb));
flag=0;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you say "unable to write" do you get any error messages?

Comment: The documentation clearly states ["inline will be removed in a future release. Use Anonymous Functions instead."](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inline.html). Any specific reasons to use inline here?

Answer (score 1):

What you're locking for is [anonymous functions](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)

```
objf = @(mb,nb)sum(V(mb)^2+V(nb)^2-2*V(mb)*V(nb)*cos(delta(mb)-delta(nb)))

objf = 

    @(mb,nb)sum(V(mb)^2+V(nb)^2-2*V(mb)*V(nb)*cos(delta(mb)-delta(nb)))

objf(1,2)
```

There you go (as far as all other variables and functions of this anonymous function are defined).